# jqGrid Loading gif: loadui when to call

Tags: jqgrid, loading, animated-gif

I am trying to see if there is a real simply way to put in a  loading gif when my jqGrid is loading data?
I have seen a couple of tutorials on stack overflow, but they are a little unclear about where and how to 
do this...
Specifically, when and where do I set loadui?  And why can't I set it to loading gif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loadtext` property from your i18n file is inserted directly into the jqGrid loading dialog, so instead of text you could add an `img` tag with a reference to a loading GIF.

For reference, the grid uses `loadtext` in the following way:

```
$("<div class='loading ui-state-default ui-state-active' id='load_"+this.id+"'>" 
 + this.p.loadtext+"</div>").insertBefore(gv);
```

Comment: is that code injected directly into the i18n file?  I am a little confused and how and when to inject any of this code?

Comment: I am unsure what you mean?  Should I replace the load text option with a reference to a gif?

Comment: @DmainEvent - Sorry, this code is just how jqGrid uses the `loadtext` field internally. You should be able to just edit your `grid.locale-XX.js` file and edit the line to be something like `loadtext: "<img src='/images/loader.gif'>",`

Comment: I can't just use the loadtext parameter from setGridParam? or initially?  ALso, I am having a hard time just getting a lodaing thing to show up altogether... please see...
http://stackoverflow.com/q/11650103/729820

Comment: Ah, I missed that it was in the list of options. Using `setGridParam` would probably work too.

Comment: I just answered your other question, but I think I might be missing something? Best to continue the discussion over there. Thank you for accepting this answer BTW :)