# jqGrid loading message wont work

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

What am I doing wrong here?  I am supposed to have a loadText, and I have one, I set my loadui to 'block'.  What on earth could I be doing wrong...

That data is being loaded with a reloadGrid command...  Maybe I should be setting the loadText and load ui then?  Here is how I set up my jqGrid...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        shrinkToFit: false,
        autowidth: true,
        datatype: 'jsonstring',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: [
                    'Last Name',
                    'First Name',
                    'DOB',
                    'Gender',
                    'EMPIID',
                    'MedipacId',
                    'EPCID'
                    ],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'Last_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'First_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'DOB', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'GENDER', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'EMPIID', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'medipacId', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'EPCID', width: 145, align: 'left' }
                ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        loadui: 'block',
        loadtext: 'Does this thing every work?',
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '/Content/themes/UPMC-theme/images',
        caption: 'Patient Return Result',
        ondblClickRow: function (id) {
            var rowData = $("#list").getRowData(id);
            var dummyURL = '@Url.Action("EditEncounter", "EditEncounterAdd", new { FirstName ="-1", LastName="-2", DOB = "-3", MRN="-4", popID = TempData["POPULATIONID"] })';
            var FName = rowData['First_Name'];
            var LName = rowData['Last_Name'];
            var DOB = rowData['DOB'];
            var MRN = rowData['medipacId'];
            var path = dummyURL.replace("-1", FName);
            var path = dummyURL.replace("-2", LName);
            var path = dummyURL.replace("-3", DOB);
            var path = dummyURL.replace("-4", MRN);
            debugger;
            document.location.href = path;
        }
    });
})
```

Thanks.
**UPDATE: Nope... That doesn't work**

**UPDATE: THE FOLLOWING IS HOW I UPDATE MY TABLE**

```
$("#list").setGridParam({
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            datastr: result,
            loadui: 'block',
            loadtext: 'what is good in the hood?',
            caption: 'Search Results'
        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

ps... the loadui, and loadtext do not show anything at all... I most be missing something....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that there is no `url` option, so the grid does not know where to load data from... or am I missing something?

Comment: I just call .setGridParam to load the data... what I do above is how I set up the table so it is initially empty.  The data is supposed to be refreshed when the user clicks search... That is why I need a loading gif over the entire grid... I will update my post

Comment: Sorry, I see what is going on here. You are using `jsonstring` to pass JSON data to the grid using `result`. In this case the loading message is never displayed because the grid is not making an AJAX request. You can either change your code to have the jqGrid make the AJAX request, or you can use another plugin to display the loading message, such as jQuery BlockUI - http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Comment: so how would I determine when to block, and when to unblock?  I know jqGrid, has an OnComplete event, but does it have a loading event?  When I do trigger.reloadGrid? would I block, and when say $('#list').complete wouid I have a function that unblocks?

Comment: You would block before you make your AJAX request (assuming that is how you get the contents of `result`). Datatype is local since you are using JSON string - see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_string for more information. As a result the `reloadGrid` is a synchronous operation, you can just unblock after it is triggered.

Comment: Well, that would complicate things, because I use Ajax.BeginForm in an MVC application instead of doing a standard form which I then keep the default activity from firing.  So I might be in a little bit of a pickle.